# How to set expected template argument base type

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, templates

I have an interface base class:

```
class BaseDicModel {
public:
  virtual ~BaseDicModel() {}
  virtual QString text() const    = 0;
  virtual int id() const          = 0;
  virtual void parseQuery(QSqlQuery *q) = 0;
  virtual QJsonObject toJson()    = 0;
};
```

and a template function, which is supposed to execute sql query and return dictionary depending on template class.

```
 template <class T>
  /**
   * @brief Loading dictionary from database
   * @param sqlQuery sql query to execute
   * @return Dictionary of type T
   * !!! T MUST BE DERIVED FROM BaseDicModel !!!
   */
  static QList<T *>
  getDictionary(QString sqlQuery) {
    QList<T *> result;
    QString conName = "regionConnection";
    {
      QSqlDatabase conn = getConnectionV2(
          conName, ConfigService::getInstance()->get_db_connection());
      //        int ret = -1;
      bool bOpen = false;
      if (!conn.isOpen()) {
        if (!conn.open()) {
          qWarning() << "Error while open db";
          return result;
        }
        bOpen = true;
      }

      QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(conn);

      query->prepare(sqlQuery);
      if (query->exec()) {
        while (query->next()) {
          T *row = new T();
          row->parseQuery(query);
          result.append(row);
        }
      } else {
        qWarning() << "Error while exec query:" << query->lastError().text();
      }
      delete query;
      if (bOpen) { conn.close(); }
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(conName);
    return result;
  }
};
```

it works fine, but i have a problem: template class can be **ANY** class right now,and what i'd like to get is template only for BaseDicModel derived classes.
Something like this pseudocode:

```
template<class T implements BaseDicModel>
```

Can you please give me any hints on how to make it work?
Question must be silly, but i don't seem to get it.
Thanks.

Comment: There are some early implementations as surrogate for c++20 concepts. IIRC boost provides such.

Comment: In C++20 you can use concepts [std::derived_from](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from), or in previous versions you could do something with SFINAE (std::enable_if_t) and [std::is_base_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of)

Comment: Which version of C++ are you on? (really C++11, or later?)

Comment: In C++20 or more, the syntax is `template<class T> requires std::derived_from<T,BaseDicModel>`, in C++14 or C++17 use of SFINAE is `template<class T,typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<BaseDicModel,T>>>`.

Comment: I wonder why you care. Why is it a problem that the function accepts any type that implements `parseQuery` method? This approach (known as "duck typing") is typical for C++ templates.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes, i have to use c++11 only

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i'd like IDE to hint available methods to be honest... Just "T" means error only in compile time, does not feel good to me

Comment: I doubt the IDE is smart enough to grok fancy SFINAE tricks and realize that `T` is constrained.

Comment: @faspowa, if you have still an error, give a example with it and the text of the error. For C++11, the template declaration syntax is heavier and becomes `template<class T,class=typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseDicModel,T>::value>::type>`

Comment: In C++11 I would try adding  `static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseDicModel,T>::value);` to the constructor. It is not so advanced as SFINAE but at least you will detect violations at build time.

Comment: `BaseDicModel` doesn't use its template parameter. Why is it ever a template?

Comment: @n.m. full base class is a template, removed extra stuff for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would just rely on duck typing and don't care, maybe apart from renaming T to something meaningful in you context, e.g. DicModel.

It gets a bit ugly pre-C++20, but it can be done by adding a second template argument. I prefer a non-type one, as it offers slightly better protection against outsmarting the check, but a type one should also do.

I guess [`is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and [`enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) are going to be the main workhorses, with the optional addition of [`is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

So, going top down, first the extra parameter should be added, I have chosen a pointer to void. The logic behind a non-type parameter is that if one tries to specify that argument manually, the check applies regardless of it:

1. `typename std::enable_if<?????>::type* = nullptr`
2. The condition inside checks if T is base of something, therefore `std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value`
3. Optionally, a second check could be added to verify whether T is not the base type itself `&& !std::is_same<T, Base>::value`
4. So putting it all together: `template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value && !std::is_same<T, Base>::value>::type* = nullptr>`

```cpp
#include <type_traits>


struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct DerivedPublic : Base{};

class DerivedPrivate : Base{};

struct DerivedFurther : DerivedPrivate{};

// derived + base
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
// derived only
// template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value && !std::is_same<T, Base>::value>::type* = nullptr>
struct S{};

int main(int, char*[])
{
    S<Base> sb;
    S<DerivedPublic> sdpub;
    S<DerivedPrivate> sdprv;
    S<DerivedFurther> sdf;
    // S<int> si;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1GhqGWEhz)